# How do I export my Test Cases from one Test Suite to another?

Tags: azure-devops, test-plan

There is a solution posted for the same question but the answer provided there is not helping. Their screenshot is not matching with the options available to me. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNTj5.png
The "Test Cases" option on the left is not there for me. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to share the detail link of that question here which could make more clearly.

But, according to your posted screenshot. Guess you **need to first install  [Test Case Explorer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TestCaseExplorer)**:

After this, you will be able to add, move or clone test suites from one test plan to another using drag and drop.

[image]

For a step by step tutorial, please kindly check this video here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TestCaseExplorer&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.vssps.visualstudio.com%2F_signedin